# Change an element in a 2D array using a mutator method Java

Tags: java, arrays, setter, mutators

I have three classes in a Battleship program I am writing, a driver, a domain, and a helper class. I wanted to change the value of an element in a 2D array of chars in my domain class using a mutator method but I keep getting a "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to a char[][]" error when trying to pass an array in the helper class to the domain class. What am I doing wrong or is there another way to do this.

```
public void hitOrMiss() {
   char[][] tUGB = bShip.getUserGameboard();
   char[][] tGB = bShip.getGameboard();
    if (bShip.getGameboard()[bShip.getUserRow()][bShip.getUserCol()] == '0') {
        System.out.println("You missed!");
        tUGB[bShip.getUserRow()][bShip.getUserCol()] = 'O';
        bShip.setUserGambeboard(tUGB[bShip.getUserRow()][bShip.getUserCol()]);
        //this.userGameboard[userRow][userCol] = 'O';
        this.misses++;
        this.chances--;

    } else {
        System.out.println("You got a hit!");
        this.hits++;
        this.chances++;
        this.userGameboard[userRow][userCol] = this.hit;
        this.gameboard[userRow][userCol] = this.hit;
    }
}
```

This is the mutator class

```
public void setUserGambeboard(char[][] aUserGameboard){
    this.userGameboard = aUserGameboard;
```

Comment: Line 7 is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code `tUGB[bShip.getUserRow()][bShip.getUserCol()]`is passing a value from the 2d array `tUGB` into a method that expects a `char[][]`.

So, the error makes sense; a `char` and `char[][]` are incompatible types.

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot, I got it. Thnak you Chief. I should have just been passing the whole array not a character in the array.